# I gave my IPS tag to someone to send a domain, neither he nor the registrar know where it's registered

Tags: web-hosting

So, like the title says, three weeks ago I sent Hostgator's IP TAG to the person who created a domain, built a website and hosted my friend's website. My friend wanted control of his own business;s domain, basically. The web designer said he sent the message to my TAG and that it should now be with my registrar, Hostgator.

However, apparently no one knows where it is. Hostgator don't appear to have it though they've been an absolute nightmare, at one point in communications making out that they saw something on their end but don't have control of it enough even to send it back.

The guy who built the website said he doesn't have it and he can't do anything from his end until it's cancelled, but the whois.net search shows that it's still registered with the old registrar.

I honestly don't have a clue who's bullshitting me here, but it's almost certain that one of the parties is. Domains don't just disappear. This is my friend's business website that he relies on for work, especially in these current times.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'll supply whatever info I can.